# Running a Python from Excel Macro

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have seen a couple posts instructing people on how to run a Python script through an Excel macro. I'm still having trouble with it - all I'm looking to do for the moment is see how I can get a Python script titled `main.py` to print `40` when I run an Excel macro. I've posted a couple filepaths below, with ellipses to replace the names of certain folders.

For background, my python.exe file is located:

```
R:\TRADING\...\Anders\python3.9 - Copy\3.9.7\python.exe
```

And the python script that I want to run is located:

```
R:\TRADING\...\Anders\Python\main.py
```

When I run `print(sys.executable)` on Python, it produces the location `//Naeast.../.../.../.../TRADING/.../Anders/Python/main.py` where `//Naeast.../.../.../.../` is the location of the `R:` drive.

Per [the response (with about 16 upvotes) to this post here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba/60658227) I implemented and ran this code below from my test Excel file to run `main.py` but it failed:

```
Sub RunPython1()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExe = """R:\TRADING\...\Anders\python3.9 - Copy\3.9.7\python.exe"""
    PythonScript = "R:\TRADING\...\Anders\Python\main.py"

    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript

End Sub
```

I was careful to include triple quotes for PythonExe.

When I try replicating the answer [to the question here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173535/running-python-script-from-vba) I get an error saying that the `Method 'Run' of object 'IwshShell3' failed.`

Comment: I think you need a space between the  arguments `PythonExe & " " & PythonScript`

Comment: @CDP1802, thank you - I tried adding the space " " in between PythonExe and PythonScript as well as adjusting the naming/path conventions for PythonScript, but this still did not end up helping my Python script run when I clicked the macro.

Comment: Are there any spaces in folder names in `R:\TRADING\...\Anders\Python\main.py`

Comment: No, there are no spaces in ```R:\TRADING\...\Anders\Python\main.py```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My python code was originally geared to edit an Excel spreadsheet directly. The use case in general was that whenever I received an email with a certain subject line - let's say `blah` for example,  I wanted a python file `main.py` to automatically execute and edit an excel file `main.xlsx` accordingly.

Something to note is that `main.xlsx` cannot be open at the time the email arrives. If anyone has any guidance on how to have `main.xlsx` be modified on the chance that the email arrives while it is open, I'd greatly appreciate it.

The below code solved my issue exactly:

```
Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim MessageInfo
Dim Result
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    Debug.Print "Arrived"
    If Item.Subject = "Blah" Then
        Const PyExe = """C:\...\...\...\...\...\python3.9\latest\python.exe"""
        Const PyScript = "R:\...\...\Anders\Python\main.py"
        
        Dim objShell As Object, cmd As String
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        
        cmd = PyExe & " " & PyScript
        Debug.Print cmd
        
        objShell.Run cmd
        objShell.exec cmd
        
        MsgBox objShell.exec(cmd).StdOut.ReadAll
    End If
End If
ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitNewItem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running Python with this test script.

```vb
Sub test()

   Const PyExe = """R:\TRADING\...\Anders\python3.9 - Copy\3.9.7\python.exe"""
   Const PyScript = "-h"
   
   Dim objShell As Object, cmd As String
   Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
   
   cmd = PyExe & " " & PyScript
   Debug.Print cmd
   
   MsgBox objShell.exec(cmd).StdOut.ReadAll
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you! I ran this and got a message box that said "Microsoft Excel ... usage: \\Naeast... ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ... Options and arguments (and corresponding environment variables" ... and then it lists a bunch of options and arguments like "-b, -B, -c, -d, -E, -h, -i, and -I" which it then explains what each does.

Comment: @Anders That's good, it should be the Python help page. Put your script file in `PyScript` to replace -h

Comment: Hey there! 'pologies for taking nearly two weeks to get back to you, but I'll comment back below - the solution was basically yours.